# Breadboard minimum lead length

Tags: components, breadboard, mechanical

What's the minimum lead length for a component in order to reliably connect with solderless breadboard contacts?

Reading specs on cables, relays LEDs, and other components, what should I take as the minimum distance from the bottom of the device to the tip of the lead?  Or put another way, from the top of the breadboard to the pinch-point of its contacts?

I want to plug into a generic solderless breadboard and not worry about loose connections.  I have assumed through-hole PC board leads would be sufficient but occasionally they are not.  Case in point, a flex cable from Digi-Key has leads that are about 3.2mm or 0.125in long that keep falling out.  So the answer may be just a little longer than that.

This [spec](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/3M%20PDFs/Solderless%20Breadboard%20Acces.pdf) from 3M says nothing about this dimension, except that the standard interconnect wires go about 0.250in deep.

Comment: You want the "minimum insertion depth" from an actual datasheet, not an ad.

Comment: "I want to plug into a generic solderless breadboard and not worry about loose connections." <-- good luck with that.

Comment: Ever seen any such data sheet @Passerby?  I couldn't find one.  It would constitute an answer, I agree.  I found that ad/spec from a datasheet link at DigiKey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard DIP has a lead length of about 0.125" (3.1mm) but the actual penetration below the surface is probably more like 4.2mm because the holes and leads are both beveled.

Comment: How do bevels make penetration deeper from 3.1 to 4.2mm, @SpehroPefhany?  I'd think lead bevels would mean less effective depth.  And hole bevels would only make penetration easier not deeper.  Have you seen a standard on dip leads?

Comment: There's probably a MIL standard, but drawings differ. Normally the bottom of the DIP package sits up above the PCB by a small amount- the spacing is set by the leadframe shape. This is by design to avoid trapping anything under the package. On a solderless breadboard, I think you'll find the bottom of the package sits right down on the plastic (don't have one in front of me).

Answer (score 2):

The pins on the male jumper cables that came with my Raspberry Pi starter kit are about 8 mm/5/16".

For a specific breadboard, I'm sure this dimension can easily be determined experimentally.

Comment: Was hoping for some kind of standard or spec I could rely on when ordering breadboards or components.  Your number may be the closest to it.

Comment: There is probably not any "Official Spec", but the breadboards are designed to hold standard DIP ICs, so you should be able to use the length of a DIP pin as a reasonable minimum insertion length.